# Reddit Search API URL?

Tags: javascript, json, api, search, reddit

I'm trying to implement a search using reddit's api, but am not having much luck:

```
http://www.reddit.com/search.json?q=ferrari?jsonp=?
```

It's returning some json formatted text but no results.. If I search "cars", it returns 2 results, and the rest of my code won't recognize the objects. (Plus, I know there's more than 2 results for cars). Any idea on how to modify the URL?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your URL looks wrong. I think you used a question mark instead of an amp to separate request variables.

I tried using `http://www.reddit.com/search.json?q=ferrari` and I got a lot of results in JSON format.

This will allow you to do the most basic search for reddit posts.

You can add other parameters, described on the reddit API page : http://www.reddit.com/dev/api#GET_search. You can also limit your search to one subreddit.

For example, to get the same results, sort by newest : `http://www.reddit.com/search.json?q=ferrari&sort=new`

Answer (score 0):

It does work for me like so :

```
http://www.reddit.com/search.json?q=rest&jsonp=callback
```

and there is limit parameter which by default is 25 and the maximum is 100

Comment: It 's now giving me some JSON formatted text, but when I put it in on a JSON viewer, I'm getting an 'Invalid JSON variable' error. My code also still won't recognize the objects.

Comment: I am using JSON view myself and it's all displayed properly no erros